# Databinding returning null. Is it normal?

Tags: android, data-binding, tabs, android-tablayout, android-databinding

I'm using databinding, and looks like tab item is returned null from databinding (but not gameTypes), is that normal? Other views are working fine, so there is no problem with implementation of databinding. Here is part of layout file.

```
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/gameTypes"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            >

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/football"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:tag="football"
                android:text="Football"
            />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/basketball"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:tag="basketball"
                android:text="Basketball"/>


        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

Here is code that I'm trying to find selected tab;

```
    private Boolean isSelectedTab(TabItem item, TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    if (tab.getTag().equals(item.getTag()))
        return true;
    return false;
    }
```

Error is; item is null which is `databinding.basketball`. I think shouldn't be null since it's `TabItem`.

Thanks.

Comment: I recommend that you edit your question and show where/how you are calling your `isSelectedTab()` method. In particular, show where/how you are getting the `item` value.

Comment: Updated @CommonsWare

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not line up with your XML, so that's probably one problem. But you might be running into an issue we had with `TabLayouts` and databinding.

The root cause appears to be that TabLayout uses `TabItem` in XML, but it converts it into a `Tab` at runtime. This screws up the internal mapping databinding uses to create its references. In our case, our `TabItem` instance was being cast from the wrong object. In your case, sounds like it might just be a null object.

In either case, it does't appear that you can use `TabLayout` with databinding reliably. We ended up creating a custom `View` that just wraps a `TabLayout` and then "binds" data to it manually by accessing its `Tab` items directly.

For example, a layout with a `TabLayout`:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>
    <variable name="viewModel" type="com.app.ViewModel" />
</data>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:onTabSelectedListener="@{viewModel.onTabSelectedListener}">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout="@layout/custom_tab_layout">

    </android.support.design.widget.TabItem>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout="@layout/custom_tab_layout">

    </android.support.design.widget.TabItem>

</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

And then a custom view that wraps that:

```
public class CustomTabLayout extends FrameLayout {
    private CustomTabLayoutBinding mBinding;

    public CustomTabLayout(@NonNull Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CustomTabLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CustomTabLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, @AttrRes int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View tabLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_tab_layout, this, false);
        addView(tabLayout);

        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            mBinding = CustomTabLayoutBinding.bind(tabLayout);
        }
    }

    public void setViewModel(@Nullable ViewModel viewModel) {
        mBinding.setViewModel(viewModel);

        if (viewModel != null) {
            updateTabAtIndex(viewModel.getFirstTabViewModel(), 0, viewModel.getSelectedIndex());
            updateTabAtIndex(viewModel.getSecondTabViewModel(), 1, viewModel.getSelectedIndex());
        }
    }

    private void updateTabAtIndex(TabViewModel tabViewModel, int index, int selectedIndex) {
        TabLayout.Tab tab = mBinding.tabLayout.getTabAt(index);
        if (tab == null) {
            return;
        }

        View customView = tab.getCustomView();
        if (customView == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (index == selectedIndex) {
            tab.select();
        }

        TextView textView = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        textView.setText(tabViewModel.getTitleText());

        TextView subTitleTV = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
        subTitleTV.setText(tabViewModel.getSubTitleText());
    }
}
```

Then in the layout that you need a TabLayout, use your custom view instead:

```
<com.app.CustomTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/custom_tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="@dimen/default_toolbar_elevation"
        app:viewModel="@{viewModel.getTabsViewModel}" />
```

We're using MVVM here, but hopefully you get the gist: by providing a public `setViewModel` (or `setMyData` or whatever) method, you can still leverage databinding where you use the custom tab layout, but then control manually setting the attributes on the `Tab` objects in the `TabLayout`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I renamed variables, so It's about wrong refactoring. I think you wrote view that wraps `Tab Layout` not `Table Layout`. Is there any example that I can take a look? I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Yeah, meant `TabLayout` - fixed and update answer with some sample how we do it.

Answer (score 0):

> item is databinding.itemBasketball

Not according to your code snippet. Your code snippet shows that you are calling `isSelectedTab(b.itemFootballTypes, tab)`. There is nothing named `itemFootballTypes` in your layout XML in your question. There is an `itemFootball` tab, though.

Comment: sorry it was about refactoring, and not the cause of problem.